# Frequent Logout in ASP.Net with IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

One of our ASP.Net 2.0 applications was recently shifted to a Windows 2008 R2 server from a Windows 2003 Server.  After this we find that users are logged out very frequently (1 or 2 minutes).

I have checked Event logs and also checked all the session time out values and tried many other solutions from google search and here, but no solution has fixed this issue yet.

Can somebody help?

Comment: You really need to work more on this question, provide more details, what type of authentication do you use (windows/forms/etc)? how do you store session (inproc/sql server/state server/etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Please also check IIS logs for application pool restarts. I assume that your session state is stored in memory (default) so it will be cleared when application pool restarts. You might also want to try ASP.NET Performance Counters to check for it

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4.aspx

Counter name is Worker Process Restarts